# sql query to groupby with a deduplicated column

Tags: sql, group-by, unique

I have the following table

```
create table events (
event_id,
event_name,
datetime,
email)
```

And I want to display the events per week, and the events per week deduplicated by emails, in a single query.

While doing:

```
select date_trunc('week', datetime) wdt, event_name, count(1) 
from events
group by wdt, event_name;



     wdt             | event_name  | count 
---------------------+-------------+-------
 2014-10-27 00:00:00 | deliver     |    32
 2014-11-17 00:00:00 | open        |    30
 2014-10-20 00:00:00 | deliver     |    25
 2014-10-20 00:00:00 | click       |    19
 2014-10-27 00:00:00 | click       |    29
```

I can get the first column, but I don't know how to have the `count_distinct` column (if two clicks for the same email, on same week, it counts for one, not two).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify which column to count only distinct values for, like this:

```
select date_trunc('week', datetime) wdt, event_name, count(distinct email) 
from events
group by wdt, event_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you just need to do a distinct 1; as you pointed out.

```
select date_trunc('week', datetime) wdt, event_name, count(distinct 1) 
from events
group by wdt, event_name;
```

however with out the raw data and some samples, I'm not sure how to confirm as I can't see why count 31 and 29 would occur for the same date (10/27) in wdt for the same event_name.

Comment: with your suggestion, I have a 1 for all lines  in count column, and the data is no longer grouped by week / event_name...

Comment: actually, to achieve what I want, I think I must use the 'email' column somewhere

Comment: I've edited the question, with the correct event for 32 count